# How to keep session alive in angular (login foncionality)

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

i using angular (typescript) and Spring boot (Java)
How i can keep session alive when i in the admin mode (login)
just the code or the fucntion to do that
and thanks

this is the service code to get all account

i know it's not secure but just for learn lol

```
public getAdmin(): Observable<Admin[]>{
    return this.http.get<Admin[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/admin/all`);
  }
```

Comment: We're not here to give you code, we're here to help you write it. did you learn about local storage and/or session storage, and tokens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular app has keep token and user details in order to keep commnication
with the server.
This token usually will be save in localStorage which is not angular related.

You can create a service like this:

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {

  constructor() { }

 public saveUser(user) {   
    localStorage .setItem(U_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));    
  }
}
```